# How do you display placeholder which is set as 'mm/dd/yyyy' instead of “1/1/0001” in date input fields when date is null?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, datepicker

I have a column in my database, of type `datetime` which may or may not be null. The front-end form should display the date in database(if any) and if it is null it should display `mm/dd/yyyy` instead of `1/1/0001` which it does when there are null values in database. So basically if there's a date in the database, it should show the date and if it's null it should return the default datepicker with '`mm/dd/yyyy`' or 'Select Date'.

My js file looks like:

```
    $scope.Changes = function (product, value) {    
        var input =
            {
                ProductId: product.ProductId,
                isActive: value,
                graceEndDate: product.graceEndDate
            }

        AdService.updateProducts(input).then(function (response) {
            if (response && response.data && response.data.isSuccessful === true) {
                DealService.showSuccess('Update successful');
            } else {
                DealService.showError('error');
            }
            product.isUpdating = false;
            $scope.loadProducts();
        }, function (error) {
            product.isUpdating = false;
            $scope.loadProducts();
            DealService.showError(error);
        });    
    }
};
```

---

My HTML looks like this:

```
<td ng-if="product.isActive === true">
  <quick-datepicker type="date" style="max-width: 175px"
                    placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" 
                    ng-model="product.EndDate"
                    disable-timepicker="true"
                    ng-change="saveChanges(product, true)">
  </quick-datepicker> 
</td>
```

Comment: set the [`placeholder` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#The_placeholder_attribute)?

Comment: you should use the html attribute called placeholder: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp

Comment: My HTML looks like this: <td ng-if="product.isActive === true">
                                                <quick-datepicker type="date" style="max-width: 175px" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" ng-model="product.EndDate" disable-timepicker="true" ng-change="saveChanges(product, true)"></quick-datepicker>
                                            </td>

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your problem is the placeholder. I'd be willing to bet that the data your front end is receiving has `product.EndDate` set to 1/1/0001 because of the `DateTime` type setting that as the default when null.

Depending on what your back end language is you can set the type to be **nullable** to fix this

Comment: It is receiving other dates as well in cases where the database entry is not null. In case the database entry is null, it returns 1/1/0001 and I want that to be replaced by blank date like 'mm/dd/yyyy'

Comment: are you saying that it's receiving the wrong date when the value is not null?

Comment: Right. For example in C# you can set the type to ```DateTime?``` which allows it to be null when it is, and sets the correct value when not null.

Comment: Another option is to use a ```string``` instead of ```DateTime```/```DateTime?```

Comment: I want the datepicker to show the placeholder value if the database entry is null

Comment: Did you verify that the value received in the JSON is actually null?

Answer (score 0):

If you used the nqQuickDate library you can easily use the placeHolder attribute to handle null values.
But double-check that your null value get from API is in the right format, sometimes null values came as string null ex: date:'null'

Comment: I am using ngQuickDate but it's still returning 1/1/0001 in the front-end form when date is null.